# How can I access stored credentials in Zeppelin within a notebook paragraph?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I would like to use some credentials in a Zeppelin notebook, however I don't want to store the credentials in the notebook if possible. I've looked at using Zeppelin datasource Credentials (documentation about that [here](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/security/datasource_authorization.html)); which explains well how to create/store the credentials, but I don't understand how to access them.

For a concrete use-case, I want to store a secret for me to access a REST API. I have some code that works if I hardcode the credentials, but I want to avoid that:

```
%pyspark
import requests

def get_sync_data(secret, sync_data_url):
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {secret}", "Content-Type": "application/json"}
    payload = "..."
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()

get_sync_data('my_secret', 'http://sync.url/api')
```

Is there some way that I can replace `'my-secret'` here with a value I fetch from Zeppelin's stored datasource Credentials?

Answer (score 1):

In version 0.8.2 you can use credential injection: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/usage/interpreter/overview.html#credential-injection

So your example could then be something like:

```
 %pyspark
import requests

def get_sync_data(secret, sync_data_url):
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {secret}", "Content-Type": "application/json"}
    payload = "..."
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()

get_sync_data('{password.my_secret}', 'http://sync.url/api')
```